# #PERCENT with a Map in SSRS 2008

Tags: reporting-services, maps, ssrs-2008-r2

I am using SSRS 2008 R2 and have the following map.

[image: Map in SSRS]

In my opinion, it looks very ugly with all of the zip codes showing for each area so what I would like to do is only show the zip code when the area has more than 10% of the total number of people in it. I was reading [here (Troubleshooting Reports)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee240843(v=sql.105).aspx#Tooltip) so I don't know if this is possible. A coworker was telling me that for Charts/Graphs in SSRS there is a #PERCENT that would allow me to do something like:

```
 Visibility Expression: =#PERCENT > 10
```

but I couldn't get it to work. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually did something extremely similar once.  I ended up just setting the label expression using a couple of aggregate functions:

```
=IIF(SUM(Fields!Quantity.Value)/SUM(Fields!Quantity.Value, "DataSet1")>0.10,Fields!ZIP.Value,"")
```

Worked fairly well.

Comment: So I think this may work for me.. I think I might have to change what my query is pulling, but thanks for the ideas!